# Create a Contact Us Form in DNN7.02

Tags: dotnetnuke, contact-form

I have just downloaded and installed DNN 7.02 version.

I have set up the SMTP server settings successfully and changed the email of host account to a valid email address. Yet the Contact Us page does not send out any email. The page is simply using HTML module.

Can someone please point me to what is required of the built in Contact Us page to work for sending emails?

Comment: I've built an open source DNN 7/8/9 contact module you can modify for your needs. You can get the source here: https://github.com/GusBeare/DNNContactForm It uses Google recaptcha so you'll need a recaptcha code to get that working. It saves all the enquiries to a table. I am working on a list where admin users can browse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Contact Us pages I always use the Feedback module http://dnnfeedback.codeplex.com/

The HTML module doesn't have the ability to send emails.

Comment: Chris - Appreciate your quick response. So the Contact Us page that I get with 7.02 install does not work. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi I followed your advise and installed the module. The problem is all feedbacks are public --> all users can see the request. Can you explain how you deal with this issue. Thank you